# Hit counter - do I need a dedicated table?

Tags: php, hitcounter

I have been reading about a variety of ways which I can take to implement a hit counter. The one that I liked the most was having a session/cookie flag for a specific user to indicate if he/she visited a specific page. If the flag is not set, I would set it and increment the page's hits by 1.

I know the above method is fine, but I also understand that it will always have a workaround. But if I use a dedicated table with a unique constraint on a combination of page_id and ip_address, it should work most efficiently when used with a combination of a session flag. But considering the site I am working on has about a 20000 hits a day (which isn't a lot, but enough to flood my hits table), is it worth flooding MySQL with ip addresses just to capture hits?

Also, is there a better way of capturing legit hits other than these?

Comment: there's only 2 ways of counting hits: cookies and IP. cookies can be wiped so you can game the system that way. and IPs can be shared by **MANY** users (e.g. a large-scale NAT gateway like AOL's). one lets the count get inflated artifically. the other HIDES multiple valid hits. hit counters on the web are at best an approximation, and generally flat out useless

Comment: Agreed, I'll take the session/cookie route then. At least they can't flood a page with hits if I keep a session data set on the server side. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can also implement server-side sessions and check those way before querying the MySQL to see if they have ever visited. It wouldn't be an issue to do something like: `if(!isset($_SESSION['counter']['pageID']))`, for example.. then query MySQL for the specific date and page of access. If it doesn't exist, then continue to insert it and set the session.

Comment: sessions are implemented via cookies. wiping cookies means "wiping" sessions. the session will still exist on your server, but the link between that session and the user who started it will have been severed

Comment: @MarcB: makes sense, I guess there is a session ID of some sort stored in the cookies on client side? But I guess, this risk is worth taking considering the performance downsides of a dedicated table..

Comment: yes. that's exactly how it works. php will set a cookie on the client that contains the ID of the session they're using. that ID is then used to load the appropriate session file when that user returns to the site. nuke the session cookie, and the user's session is "lost", and php sees them as a brand new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is just too much work to have dedicated table for this.
Do it only if really required. Otherwise it is just a waste of time and resources.
Field in existing table that gets incremented, and eventually a cookie to disable incrementing on refresh is just fine.

Comment: Indeed. I guess I'll take the session/cookie route then. Thanks for the answer!